# can't use tesseract so how to install tesseract on virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, tesseract

I created a virtualenv via command venv. Then I installed tesseract via command `brew install tesseract`. But I can use it only on actual env, when I use it on virtualenv, an error *No such file or directory: 'tesseract'* is thrown:

```
BlockquoteTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/spider/demo2.py", line 5, in <module>
    vcode = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
  File "/Users/abc/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/Users/abc/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'
```

Comment: yep i have both python2.7 and python 3.5 on my system@Ajeets

Comment: yes they are same `/usr/local/bin/brew` why they should be different?python's virtual env only separate python interpreter and its library from global ,should i install other homebrew for virtual env?or i should install two tesseract on my system? the virtual env is the same as virtual machine?@Ajeets

Comment: the python interpreter on v.env has its own pip ,i install pillow and pytesseract for v.env the beautifulsoup can be userd only on v.env ,but i can't use tesseract on v.env and it can be used on global env……@Ajeets

Comment: my network is poor now ,can you tell me should i install two tesseract on my system ?@Ajeets

Comment: Tesseract and pytesseract are different. Tesseract that you have installed can be used anywhere and not just in the venv. Pytesseract is a python wrapper for tesseract and if you install that in venv then it should work in the venv.

Comment: Also, you would need to install both of them before you start using commands like pytesseract.image_to_string(image).

Comment: yep ,using python3.5 with pytesseract ,we should change SC in pytesseract.py `tesseract_cmd='tesseract'` .pytesseract can not find the Symbolic Link or executable file of tesseract ,we should write the full path.@GouravChawla

Comment: Could you also mention which version of tesseract and pytesseract are you using?